# Can /u/<userID> redirect to /users/<userID> even for deleted users (for moderators)?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, deleted-accounts, redirection

For a non-deleted user, following a link of the form `<sitename>.stackexchange.com/u/<userID>` will redirect to the user page `<sitename>.stackexchange.com/users/<userID>`. (Try it on this random user: https://meta.stackexchange.com/u/278659 )

For a deleted user, trying to visit their user page will result in a "Page Not Found" error unless one is a diamond moderator on the site in question. So when I visit, for example, [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/85094), I see a stub as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294866/278659). But the `/u/<userID>` page doesn't redirect to there: when I click [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/u/85094), I see the same "Page Not Found" error as you!

**Please can the `/u/<userID>` page redirect to the `/users/<userID>` stub even for deleted users?**

<sub>This may look like a stupidly trivial request, but [Smokey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301/278659), a network-wide user-maintained spam/rubbish detector, reports bad posts with a link to the `/u/<userID>` page and not the `/users/<userID>` one. Thus, for instance, when I see a [report](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38315334#38315334) of a nonsense post from a user with an inappropriate username, and click the user link to delete or rename the user if necessary, then if another mod has already done the needful, I have to manually edit the URL from `u` to `users` in order to check exactly what happened.</sub>

Comment: Maybe Smokey should be modified to use the canonical link.

Comment: @ale https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/pull/879

Comment: ^ CI failing; I'm holding off merge until that's fixed :)

Comment: @ale Those four characters can be more valuable than you'd think. It'd be better all around for the canonical link to work as folks would expect.

Comment: That Smokey PR is now live, BTW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with the next build this has been implemented.

The short-style `/u/{id}` redirect will work for deleted users (assuming the viewing users is a moderator) if we still have a record of their deletion (various things might result in there not being a record, but generally there is one).  If there is no record, we'll continue to 404 as we do now.

Comment: Just curious, what exactly can cause a removal of the record? A GDPR request? Something else?

Comment: Legal things mostly, GDPR, underaged user, if somehow there's content that we cannot legally keep around (IP, PII, etc.).